# Query values from separate sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to figure out how to query values from Sheet2 into Sheet1 where column A in Sheet1 matches column A (strings) in Sheet2, and return only the max value of column D (integer) from Sheet2.

Here's what I am using:

```
=Query(Sheet2!A:F,CONCATENATE("Select D where Name =",A2))
```

I have tried using `Select max(d)...` and `=MAX(Query(...))` but neither worked for me.

What would be the correct way to do this?

Example data:

```
Sheet1
Name      ColB      Date      Check      Oldest
Bob       Y         2/14/2013 4/14/2013     5

Sheet2
Name      Title     Date      Age
Bob       Foo       2/1/2013  3
Boo       Bar       2/4/2013  5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may serve, if entered in the cell presently containing `Oldest` (which would then be overwritten with `max Age`:

```
=query(Sheet2!A:D,"select max(D) where A ='Bob' ")
```

but the result for your sample would be `3` rather than the `5` as shown to be required.

Comment: Close, but got me what I needed.  I had tried the =Bob before, but didn't work; I probably typed something wrong.
I was hoping to be able to use a "...A = Sheet1!A2" so I could just pull down the values to other cells for other names.  At least the name list wont change often, so just a bit of manual work to set it up isn't too bad.

however, here's what actually worked for me, with the correct result:
`=MAX(query(Sheet2!A:D,"select D where A ='Bob' ") )`